# how to get count of file with multiple keyword in GetFiles

Tags: c#, file, keyword

I want to show how many files with specific extension (jpg,jpeg,png,psd, or etc..) in some folder. But also must with specific keyword like "10*" or "1A*". In first, I make some code with extension only, then i get the count of the files in some folder. but i try to make second code for to get count of files with specific name and specific extension but having difficulties.

i have tried adding "where" after getfiles but still can't and get error.

Here is first code :

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"" + folderpath );
string extension = "jpg";
int count = folder.GetFiles("*." + extension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
```

And here second code with keyword and extension :

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"" + folderpath );
string extension = "jpg";
string keyword = "1A";
int count = folder.GetFiles( keyword + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => s.EndsWith("." + format )).Count;
```

The result still error. what do I need to change to make the code work properly using keywords and extensions?

Comment: `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` returns a `FileInfo[]`, but you try to apply a filter `Where(fi => fi.EndsWith...)`. Note that a `FileInfo` instance is not a `string`. So maybe you wan to use `Where(fi => fi.Name.EndsWith...)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks, you give me best clue, i using your first statment and it's works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it all with LINQ:

```
string[] prefixes = new[] { "10", "1A" };
string[] suffixes = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "psd" };

int count = folder.GetFiles().Count(f => prefixes.Any(p => f.Name.StartsWith(p)) && suffixes.Any(s => f.Extension == s));
```